# How to get data using redux from api?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Hi my friends i'm going to get data from api using redux My codes can be found in the link below if you need to change the codes

this is my project Link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/getdatafromapiwhithaxiosusingreduxinreactproject-s8ckq

I have received data from api but how can it be used in components?

Comment: Your code is error: ModuleNotFoundError. I guess that isn't error that you want to show now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the relevant code here directly. For tips on creating a good code example to illustrate what you are asking about., read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created a `Reducer.js` file

You need to create to have that file, and have a reducer in it.

Export the reducer using `export default reducer;`

After getting the data into your props object, say, `products`, you will need to map it like so:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return {
        this.props.products.map((product, i) => (
            <li>product.title</li>
        ))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: now i have a reducer file but i have one problem check project link

Comment: Props are not valid react objects. You generally need to map the props to some kind of a component. Lets say you have a prop `list`. You would need to convert it into React Objects. I have edited my answer to include the answer for your question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have products from your redux store in your `props.products` thanks to your `mapStateToProps`.